# Send individual emails using AWS SES

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have an array (UsersMails) that has all the addresses I want to send the email to. This array has 60 addresses and I know SES only can handle 50 addresses per mail. What I want to do is to send 60 individual emails in a loop but not working. It only sends the first 50, that is the reason I want to send individually.

```
var UserMails = result.map(c => c.ID);

    for (let i = 0; i < UserMails.length; i++) {
        var MessageToId = UserMails[i]
      const params = {
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: [MessageToId] // Email address/addresses that you want to send your email
        },
        //ConfigurationSetName: <<ConfigurationSetName>>,
        Message: {
          Body: {
            Html: {
              // HTML Format of the email
              Charset: "UTF-8",
              Data:
                "<html><body><p style='color:black'>" + BroadCastDesc + "</p>"+
                "</body></html>"
            },
          },
          Subject: {
            Charset: "UTF-8",
            Data: BroadCastTitle
          }
        },
        Source: "hello@outlook.com"
      };
      const sendEmail = ses.sendEmail(params).promise();

      sendEmail
      .then(data => {
        console.log("email submitted to SES", data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

      return resolve(response);
```

Comment: SES has rate limits too, you might be hitting that.  What is the error or exception?

Comment: It is not about limit, I have 50000 emails per day. I am just wondering how to split the array with the address and send 60 mails, instead of one with 50 addresses

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code? This doesn't show the code where the email is sent, only the configuration of the parameters.

Comment: is `UserMails` a multi dimensional array? The code you have currently breaks up `UserMails` and sends an email to a single `UserMail` in a loop. So unless `UserMails[0]` is an array of 50+ strings, the code you shared does what you're trying to do.

Comment: This were I defined UsersMail. I have those emails from a table in MySql and I mapped them. var UserMails = result.map(c => c.ID);

Comment: What is this code running in? A Lambda? A NodeJs server?

Comment: Correct, a lambda function. The arrays is like this [{ID: "email1@outlook.com"}, {ID: "correo2@outlokk.com"}]

Comment: Does your lambda include `async` in the call? Are you sure you are sending exactly 50 each time? I suspect you are using a promise on your lambda but not `await`ing the response and not returning the promise, so the lambda is exiting before all have been sent.

Comment: what's the execution time for your lambda?

Comment: OP is using promises, not `async await`

Comment: The OP is handling the promise. "Once a Promise is fulfilled or rejected, the respective handler function (onFulfilled or onRejected) will be called asynchronously (scheduled in the current thread loop)." So if the code that this code lives in is using a promise the function will exit before the `then` is fired. The partial results would be because some of the code gets to run due to the looping, but as soon as the looping is done no more code would execute.